# Как обработать элемент, полученый с помощью .clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код, который клонирует данные из одного ДОМ-элемента в другой.

```
$(".inv_item").click(function(event){
    $(".set").append($(this).clone());                          
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Как можно теперь работать с этим "клонированым" элементом ? Даже если делаю ...

```
    $(".inv_item").click(function(event){
        alert("Click);
    });
```

... то клонированые элементы, которые имеюткласс .inv_item игнорируются. Как это можно исправить ?

Comment: делегированием http://api.jquery.com/on/ `$('.set').on('click', '.inv_item', function(event) { ... });`

Comment: Работает ! Добавьте в ответы, я галочку поставлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делегированием - http://api.jquery.com/on

```
$('.set').on('click', '.inv_item', function(event) { 
  ... 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, здесь не нужен clone и remove

Здесь нужен простой [*append*](http://api.jquery.com/append/), так как при применении его к существующему элементу, он просто перемещает его в новый контейнер. Все события при это остаются привязанными.

```js
$('.item').click(function() {
  $('#dst').append(this);
});

$('.item').click(function() {
  $(this).text(+$(this).text() + 1);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
}
#src {
  border-color: red;
}
#dst {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="src">
  <span class="item">0</span>
  <span class="item">0</span>
  <span class="item">0</span>
  <span class="item">0</span>
  <span class="item">0</span>
  <span class="item">0</span>
  <span class="item">0</span>
</div>
<div id="dst">
</div>
```

Кроме того, [функция clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) принимает первым параметром флаг, указывающий копировать ли привязанные обработчики событий и значения *data*. По умолчанию, значение *false*, поэтому для копирования вместе с событиями нужно передать *true*.

```js
$('.item').click(function() {
  $(this).text(+$(this).text() + 1);
});

$('.item').click(function() {
  $('#dst').append($(this).clone(true));
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
}
#src {
  border-color: red;
}
#dst {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="src">
  <span class="item">0</span>
  <span class="item">0</span>
  <span class="item">0</span>
  <span class="item">0</span>
  <span class="item">0</span>
  <span class="item">0</span>
  <span class="item">0</span>
</div>
<div id="dst">
</div>
```